# Open source issue/bug tracker with image copy/paste functionality needed

Tags: github, issue-tracker

I am looking for **open source** and (free for small teams up 15 people) **issue/bug tracker**, that has following features:

- **Web based**
- **Ability to copy/paste images from clipboard** (like in GitHub issues,
  GitLab issues, Jira, GMail, etc.)
- Email notification (new issues,
  changes, comments, etc.)
- Multiple assignee (or "CC List" like in
  Bugzilla)
- Some classification (like in Bugzilla) or tags/labels (like in GitHub)
- Deadlines
- File attachments

**Nice to have features:**

- Integrated wiki, forums, etc.
- Email Reports (for example - deadlines)
- Custom fields
- Some text formatting (like Markdown)

**Notes:**

- Bugzilla, Trac, Mantis almost fit, but they don't have copy/paste images feature
- GitLab issues almost fits, but there is no multiple assignee feature
- GitHub issues fits, but no free version
- Jira fits, but no free version

Comment: What about [Phabricator](https://www.phacility.com/) don't know if it has any copy paste functionality, though

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - wow! I searched a lot, but could not find this gem. It supports copy / paste AFAIK, but need to check on my server. Looks promising. Not sure about multiple assignee feature.

Comment: Hava a look also at open project! https://www.openproject.org

Comment: @GabrieleCiech - looks good, but there is no multiple assignee feature.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - you can make Phabricator as answer. I will accept that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Phabricator](https://www.phacility.com)

I'm not a coder or anything, I've only ever used it from a visitor point of view, but the guys over at the [Blender Foundation](https://www.blender.org) use a self hosted Phabricator instance to manage their projects.

[Blenders Developer](https://developer.blender.org) is their project management and bug reporting portal and runs on phabricator.

It is a relatively complex medium sized application and it seems to work well in my purely user point of view.

It supports projects, assignees, subscribers, patches and review system with diffs, comments and images.

As far as i know it can be extended with additional modules that may also include a wiki, if I'm not mistaken